# Strange browser description PyQt

Tags: javascript, python, qt, pyqt, qtwebkit

I was trying to get browser description using JavaScript, and got strange result:

```
productSub: 20100101 # When I open it with my Mozila FF browser
productSub: 20030107 # when I open it with PyQt4

vendorSub: # nothing in here with my Mozila FF
vendorSub: Apple Computer, Inc. # with PyQt4 ( even though I don't have anything to do with Apple)
```

This is HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="myp">Hi</p>

<script>
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var nav_div = document.createElement('div');
    nav_div.id = 'nav_div';
    for (para in navigator) {
        var para_p = document.createElement('p');
        var context = document.createTextNode(para + ': ' + navigator[para]);
        para_p.appendChild(context);
        para_p.id = para;
        nav_div.appendChild(para_p);
    }
    body.appendChild(nav_div);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Python/PyQt4 code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys, signal


class MySettings(QWebPage):
    def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
        return 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0'

class Opener(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        url = QUrl('/home/john-the-ripper/JavaScript/w.html')
        self.setPage(MySettings())
        self.load(url)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    opener = Opener()
    # press Ctrl + C for exit
    if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

As you can see I have defined user agent the same as it is in my machine:

```
userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
```

## **Here is the result for PyQt4:**

[image: PyQt4]

## **And Here is the result for my native browser Mozila Fire Fox:**

[image: FF]

So the questions are:

1. Why `productSub` appers to be different, even though I have defined it in `userAgentForUrl()`
2. Why when I open this page with PyQt4, `vendorSub` is `Apple Computer, Inc.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible workaround is by redefining the `navigator` object. For a start, connect the [javaScriptWindowObjectCleared](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebframe.html#javaScriptWindowObjectCleared) signal from the page's main frame to a slot:

```
connect(myPage->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()),
  this, SLOT(tweakNavigatorObject()));
```

In your slot, execute some script ([QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript)) which can totally redefine the object, e.g.

```
window.navigator = {
  appCodeName: 'Mozilla',
  appName: 'Netscape',
  vendor: 'My Company'
}
```

JFYI, this is the trick I have used in PhantomJS to provide the ability to manipulate the global object before the page's script gets executed, useful e.g. to [manipulate Math.random](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/09/water-lily.html) behavior and to detect [user agent sniffing](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/10/detecting-browser-sniffing-2.html).

Answer (score 1):

Who says that the information in the `navigator` object is solely based on the `UserAgent` header? That header is only meant to be sent to servers when retrieving a URL. Yes, *some* values on the `navigator` object are taken from the current header, but, as you have found out, not all are, nor are they meant to.

In fact, only the `appVersion` and `userAgent` strings are taken from that header, everything else reflects the native browser instead.

The Qt browser is based on [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/), which is a Apple project, hence the vendor string. You can see that when you run your `navigator` reflection code in Safari:

```
geolocation: [object Geolocation]
cookieEnabled: true
language: en-us
productSub: 20030107
product: Gecko
appCodeName: Mozilla
mimeTypes: [object MimeTypeArray]
vendorSub:
vendor: Apple Computer, Inc.
platform: MacIntel
appName: Netscape
appVersion: 5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17
userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17
plugins: [object PluginArray]
onLine: true
javaEnabled: function javaEnabled() { [native code] }
getStorageUpdates: function getStorageUpdates() { [native code] }
```

Safari let's me switch the `UserAgent` header too, from the `Developer` menu. Switching it *only* changes the `appVersion` and `userAgent` strings too. Switching to `Firefox 11.0 — Mac`, for example, changes *just* those two variables to:

```
appVersion: 5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
```

Another browser based on WebKit is Chrome, and it's `navigator` information is quite similar:

```
geolocation: [object Geolocation]
onLine: true
cookieEnabled: true
vendorSub:
vendor: Google Inc.
productSub: 20030107
product: Gecko
mimeTypes: [object MimeTypeArray]
plugins: [object PluginArray]
platform: MacIntel
userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11
language: en-US
appVersion: 5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11
appName: Netscape
appCodeName: Mozilla
doNotTrack: null
javaEnabled: function javaEnabled() { [native code] }
getStorageUpdates: function getStorageUpdates() { [native code] }
webkitStartActivity: function webkitStartActivity() { [native code] }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So are there any ways to change `vendor`, `vendorSub` and `productSub` when using PyQt?

Comment: let's say I want to have exactly the same output as my native browser, is it possible to do with PyQt?

Comment: Not without changing the source of WebKit, no.